# print(f.read()) io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Tags: python

```
import os

path = os.getcwd()
print(path)
filename = "aboutPython.txt"
file = path + '\\' + filename
print(file)

# open a local txt file for append
f = open(file, "a")

# read the entire file
print(f.read())

# read the first 250 characters
print(f.read(5))

# read one line
print(f.readline())

# you can append because of how the file was opened  
f.write("Now the file has one more line!")
print(f.read())
```

This code throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/wrk/weemos/append_file.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(f.read())
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Comment: maybe try `f.seek(0)` to reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 0):

First open your file in read `r` mode to read it:

```
f = open(file, "r")
# read the entire file
print(f.read())

# read the first 250 characters
f.seek(0)
print(f.read(5))

# read one line
f.seek(0)
print(f.readline())
f.close()
```

Now, open it again in append `a` mode to append and then open it in read `r` mode again since you read from it later as well:

```
f = open(file, "a")
# you can append because of how the file was opened  
f.write("Now the file has one more line!")
f.close()
f = open(file, "r")
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

Comment: Share a pastebin of your code or edit it in your question. See the latest edit, also don't mix up the new changes with existing ones in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The script fails because a file opened in append mode and does not have read permissions. Open in "a+" mode if you want the file to also be writable.

```
import os

path = os.getcwd()
print(path)
filename = "aboutPython.txt"
file = os.path.join(path, filename)
print(file)

# open a local txt file for append
f = open(file, "a+")

# read the entire file
print(f.read())
```

Now the file is readable, but its positioned at the end of file so `f.read()` will return an empty string. You could

```
print("position at open", f.tell())
f.seek(0)
print("position after seek", f.tell())
```

But now I'm really just guessing what you want this script to do.